# Wordpress keeps caches old style scripts

Tags: wordpress, caching

Good Day All

I have a wordpress site. Now I am using a theme annd I am substantially overwriting the styles in the stylesheet (style.css) by using inline styles and !important. Problem is that when I refresh the browser, the old styles return. When I press ctrl + f5, my new styles are applied. Ok fine you think... Problem is that even when I completely erase my browsers history, cookies etc, and i load the page with f5, it loads the old styles again. So the only time when it actually loads my new styles are when I press ctrl+f5. I tried different browsers and I do not have any cache plugins on my site...

What can the problem be?
Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to post the question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem? Browsers like to cache. Where your theme includes the CSS, force the browser to update it when you are happy with it, e.g. `style.css?1` once, the next time use `style.css?2`. This doesn't affect the CSS, just forces it to refresh any cached versions.

Comment: @popnoodles - How do I do that? the styles.css?1/2/3 thing?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>?1" media="screen" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers like to cache. In your header where the stylesheet is included append `?1`, `?2`, etc, and update each time to force browsers to refresh your stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>?1" media="screen" />
                                                                                 ^^
```

or it could look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/filename.css?1" media="screen" />
                                                                                                  ^^
```

This won't affect the CSS contained within it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not working. Isn't your php code suppose to show: <?php echo bloginfo instead of just <?php bloginfo?

Comment: OK I see. It still does not work. Something inside the script overwrites my css. I solved it by making a second css file name style1.css and adding it after the original one in the head...But thanks for your answer, it is definitely something I will use in the future.

Comment: I had the same problem, but the solution doesn't work. My file on the server has changed, but when I fetch the file directly using my browser, with or without version number, after clearing browser cache, I still see the old file. I tried on all browsers.

Comment: @afilina That shouldn't be possible. With the querystring appended the URL is different and won't exist in cache if it's new. NB anything after a `#` is ignored by the server.